# Selenium C#: Taking a picture of a active screen instead of whole web page

Tags: c#, selenium, screenshot

I am trying to take a screnshot in my Automation Project. I would like to know is is that any way to take a screenshot of active screen which you see on your browser instead of whole web page.

(Optional) Also, I am saving it in png format but the image is in low quality is there any way to capture in High quality?

Below is my screenshot code

```
 class Result
    {
        public static void screenshot() 
        {

            ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = PropertiesCollection.driver as ITakesScreenshot;
            Screenshot screenCapture = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
            string path = @"..\..\Results\";

            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss");
            screenCapture.SaveAsFile(@path + i + ". " + timestamp + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);


        }
    }
```

Actual Result:
Click to [View](http://postimg.org/image/hd9b6t83p/). As Image is too big I have created a URL to see that image.

Expected Result: Click to [View](http://postimg.org/image/7k03xhkvf/). This is an active screen on your browser.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the context where your test cases are executed, the browser window might not be visible and thus cannot be captured by regular screen capturing. Selenium has the advantage that it directly asks the browser for the capture, so you will get a proper result even if the browser window is hidden behind another window or there is no screen context at all (e.g. on some test case runner platform like TFS or Jenkins).

In your `screenCapture.SaveAsFile()`, you can specify a different image file format. I'm using Jpeg, and the quality is good enough for me. If you want lossless quality, try Bmp format.

Comment: I get it but instead capturing whole page, there should be some way to get  an image for only that part which is available on your screen. **Please see my images under actual and expected result**